# Clustering of data - Pre- processing of data

Tags: cluster-analysis

These days I am using some clustering algorithm and I just wanted to ask a question related to this field. Maybe those who are working in this field already have this answer.

During clustering I need to have some training data which I am going to cluster. The number of iterations (e.x. K-Means algorithm) is depended on the number of training data(number of vectors). Is there any method to find the most important data from training data. What I mean is: Instead of training the K-Means with all the data maybe there is a method to find just the important vectors (those vectors who affect most the clusters) and use these "important" vectors(from training data) to traing the algorithm.

I hope you understood me. 
Thank You for reading and trying to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Training" and "Test" data is a concept from classification, not from cluster analysis.

K-means is a statistical method. If you want to speed it up, running it on a large enough random sample should give you nearly the same result.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse.Actually I am trying to speed up SOM. I was thinking for a pre-processing of data, ex. finding most important vectors from the dataset and train SOM in first iteration with those vectors. Maybe it would affect the construction of a better map and also a fast converge of algorithm itself. As we know some data affects the nodes more and some of them have a negative effect in updating weights of nodes. Maybe it should be a method to find those vectors that may affect weights of nodes more in a positive way.

Comment: Well, on k-means it's the outliers that affect the result more, but not for the better... I don't know much about SOM. Either way, have you tried speeding it up by processing a sample first, then only refining on the full data set?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse.I am sorry but I couldnt understand "refining on the full data set"...processing first a sample and then what should I do with the remaining data from the dataset? Thnx a lot for helping

Comment: Just continue the same process with the full data set, using the output from the sample as initial values. Think of k-means: on the sample you will get cluster centers that you can use as seed cluster centers for the full data set. Statistics says that the cluster centers obtained for the sample will be almost those of the full data set, and thus you probably just need 1-2 iterations on the full data set.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse.I dont know if I understood clearly but this is how I understood. Ex. for K-Means: 
1. Give random values to cluster centers.
2. Process the first sample (random). As we know in this step only value of the closest center with the sample value will be changed right? What about the other centers?
3. ...This step depends on the previous one...(I couldnt understand how to continue here). 

If you can please explain again to me :).

Comment: Step A) run 20 iterations of k-means with random seeds on 5% of your data. Step B) use the cluster centers from step A and run k-means on the complete set of data. Try for yourself and count the number of iterations needed in step B. It should drop substantially (if your data clusters).

Comment: @Anony-Mousse.Well finally I understand now. Thnx a lot for these answers. I really appreciate it :). I will try it this weekend.